# Receiving JSON-formatted data in a Web API 2 action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a RESTful API using JSON for the input and output - requests coming in should have JSON formatted bodies containing relevant data and the response will similarly be JSON formatted.

The problem I'm having is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to collect the information from the POST request and have it properly mapped to the relevant objects.

For example, I want to allow POST requests for "/contacts" which will contain a JSON formatted Contact object similar to this:

```
{"Given":"John", "Surname":"Doe"}
```

The problem is, no matter what I try I can't get the receiving action to recognise this information.  How do I access the JSON object submitted in the request body, within my action?

```
[RoutePrefix("contacts")]
public class ContactsController : BaseController
{
    [Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostContacts(FormDataCollection data)
    {
        ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse();

        response.Data = data;

        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

The response always contains a null value for "response.Data" and when I debug the application I can see that "data" is in fact null.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention how I'd *like* this to work.  Ideally I want my action to have a signature similar to this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostContacts(Contact contact) {}
```

Where the contact variable is populated automatically based off the JSON included in the incoming request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Contact` class has same property names as in JSON object,

```
   publc class Contact {
        public string Given { get; set; }
        public string Surname{ get; set; } 
    }
```

then Web API will bind the object for you

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostContacts(Contact data)
    {
        ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse();
        response.Data = data;    
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Still if it is not working, you might need to show how you are posting your data.

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried this but I have no idea what I was doing wrong.  I tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the object from the body like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostContacts([FromBody]Contact contact) {}
```

This should automatically populate your `Contact` object if your properties on the json object are named appropriately. That way you won't have to use the FormDataCollection at all.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, thanks.  It turns out the `[FromBody]` annotation isn't required so I've accepted the other answer, but I just wanted to note here (for others who might come across this question) that this answer also works.

Comment: It all depends on how you submit your data, I just assumed that you had already tried without [FromBody] ;) However, if you're submitting your json data in the request body you'd need [FromBody] to make sure web api loads it correctly.

Comment: I actually agree with you and that's how I thought it had to work as well, but I'm submitting the data in the request body and it's still working correctly even without the `[FromBody]` annotation.  Perhaps this is a Web Api v1 vs Web Api v2 difference or something like that?  I wish I could accept two answers!

Comment: Might be that it's smart enough to try both approaches. Anyway, here's an article on the subject by Mike Wasson that's illuminating: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api