# Web API Parameters are always Null

Tags: jquery, json, rest, odata

I am trying to find out why I cant pass on a Json string to my Rest API.

I created this project in VS 2015 using WebAPI and Entityframework. Odata V3 Controller and the entity classes are auto generated by the VS. GET, and DELETE methods work fine. but update and add methods are not working because I could not pass my Json object to my rest api post and put method. Parameter is always empty.

Here is my auto generated Customer entity class.

```
 public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Customer customer)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Customers.Add(customer);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Created(customer);
    }

    // PUT: odata/Customers(5)
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Customer>     patch)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(key);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Put(customer);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CustomerExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(customer);
    }
```

This is my Jquery Call

```
var customerData = {
        CustomerID: "0",
        FirstName: FirstName,
        LastName: LastName,
        Address: Address,
        PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber,
        Email: Email
    };

    var requestBody = JSON.stringify(customerData);
    return $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "POST",                  
        data: requestBody
    });
```

Here is my fiddler

```
POST http://localhost:1360/odata/Customers/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:1360/Pages/Customers.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Connection: Keep-Alive
   Content-Length: 101
   Host: localhost:1360
   Pragma: no-cache

```
 {"CustomerID":0,"FirstName":"wer","LastName":"wer","Address":"wer","PhoneNumber":"wer","Email":"wer"}
```

None of the related posts that worked for others works for me:

[Receiving JSON-formatted data in a Web API 2 action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155504/receiving-json-formatted-data-in-a-web-api-2-action)

[jQuery AJAX post data is null in c# web api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114888/jquery-ajax-post-data-is-null-in-c-sharp-web-api-controller)

Thanks in advance. Please let me know what is wrong with the code and how to fix it.

Comment: Haven't used odata3 in a while, but i would think put/post would not use delta, only a patch operation would. What if you try Customer instead of Delta<Customer> in your method signature?

Comment: This code is auto-generated by VS. though the post method has only customer in the signature, I get null value while debugging. though the json string is sent. server is not able to deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I should have added contentType:"application/json" in my Ajax call. as soon as I updated my request, the code started to work.

Thanks hope this might help.